# Regex to recognise repeating characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex to locate pairs of BELL characters in a string.

My problem is that with my current solution I will - if I have 6 Bell chars after another find a match between 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6 but I also need to find that 2 and 3 are a pair and 4 and 5. I have made a picture of how it looks like from regex.com that will probably make it very apparent what my challenge is.

I realize that I could split the string for every Bell and loop through the result and check for every empty instance but since I will be processing rather large files I assume that regex could be more efficient.

[image: picture from regex showing match in current code]

The purpose is to be able to replace empty values with something else. I cannot write BELL in this form field but in the below example i am using `.` to represent BELL. Input could be `.0......2.` and I would like to make that `.0.999.999.999.999.999.2.` but currently I am getting `0..999..999..999.2.`.

The code is like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(dir + "Temp5\\" + filname + ".csv"); 
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(dir + "Final\\" + filname + ".csv")) 
{
    foreach (string line in lines) 
    {
        cleanline = Regex.Replace(line, @"", "999");
        sw.WriteLine(line2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the picture does not help. What is the language? Text input for testing? Expected result?

Comment: I am using c# and the purpose is to be able to replace empty values with something else. I cannot write BELL in this form field but in the below example i am using . to represent BELL
Input could be .0......2. and I would like to make that .0.999.999.999.999.999.2. but currently I am getting 0..999..999..999.2.

Comment: Then please share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match 6 bell chunks with a regex like `"(?<!\a)\a{6}(?!\a)"`, and then insert `999` in between each char inside a match evaluator.

**Details**:

- `(?<!\a)` - (a negative lookbehind) there must be no bell char before the current location
- `\a{6}` - 6 bell chars
- `(?!\a)` - (a negative lookahead) there must be no bell char after the current location

See a [demo](https://ideone.com/2Hw6HW) (but using a dot for better visibility):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = " .2 1..2 .0......2.";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, "(?<!\\.)\\.{6}(?!\\.)", 
            m => string.Join("999", m.Value.Select(Char.ToString)) ));
    }
}
```

To just add `999` after each bell char that is followed with a bell char, use

```
cleanline = Regex.Replace(line, "\a(?=\a)", "$&999")
```

Comment: I do not know how many pairs of bell's there will be. it could be 3 bell chars in a row or 6 or.. and I need to find everytime two bell chars are following each othre

Comment: Then did you try `Regex.Replace(line, "\a(?=\a)", "$&999")`? I posted it earlier as a comment, but got no feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could use positive look behind to make it work:

```
(?<=・)・
```

https://regex101.com/r/tSJLZF/1

**Positive Lookbehind (?<=・)**

Assert that the Regex below matches
・ matches the character ・ literally (case sensitive)
・ matches the character ・ literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I can see that this gives me number 2 of all Bell chars but I am to naive when it comes to regex patterns to be able to turn that into something that enables me to find the space inbetween the BELLs

Comment: @Bispen: Sorry I don't get what you mean here :(

Answer (score 0):

If there are an unknown number of bell characters in the input string and you want to insert a `999` between adjacent bell characters then a simple approach is to just use a `string.Replace` method.

The code below uses semicolons (ie `;`) rather than bell characters.

```
char bellCharacter = ';';
string twoAdjacentBells = new string(bellCharacter, 2);
string twoBellsWith999 = bellCharacter + "999" + bellCharacter;
string inputLine = "abc;;def;;;;ghi";
string outputLine = inputLine
    .Replace(twoAdjacentBells, twoBellsWith999)
    .Replace(twoAdjacentBells, twoBellsWith999);
```

Two calls of `Replace` are needed to correctly handle the case of three adjacent bell characters.

Another approach is to split the input string on bell characters, scan the resultant list of strings, replace empty strings with `999` and then reassemble the pieces. The code would be something like:

```
string oneBell = new string(bellCharacter, 1);
string[] pieces = inputLine.Split(bellCharacter);
for (int ii=0; ii<pieces.Count(); ii++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pieces[ii]))
    {
        pieces[ii] = "999";
    }
}
string anotherOutputLine = string.Join(oneBell, pieces);
```